# I triple booted Windows 8 with Ubuntu 14.04 and Pear OS 8... but then I ran into a big problem

Tags: boot

I first installed the Ubuntu.  Then I partitioned my hard drive and I installed the Pear.  Finally the last operating system that I wanted to install was Windows 8, so I did so.  However now that I installed the Windows 8 there is no grub screen or any boot screen it just goes straight to Windows 8.  Is there a way to somehow fix this... because it's like I don't have any other operating systems on my computer now... I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start live boot with ubuntu 14.04 (select Try ubuntu option)
- Open terminal command using
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Type follow command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  `sudo apt-get install grub2 grub-pc`

  then run:

  `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot your computer and remove Ubuntu live boot device (ex: DVD or
  USB drive).

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I recently re-installed window, subsequently left with no grub menu. Here is how to reinstall grub from a live-disk.

Part One:

First

Login using a LiveDVD (or USB) of Ubuntu and open a terminal to type the following command to list your partitions . . .

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

This assumes Ubuntu is on your first hard drive "sda" of course it may be "sdb" or something else.

Here is an example of the output . . .

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       13206     6655792+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2           13207      232581   110565000    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          228706      232484     1904616   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6           13207      228705   108611464+  83  Linux
```

Next,

We need to mount /dev/sda6, the Ubuntu partition. Remember, your partition number very likely may not be sda6 so change the number appropriately . . .

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
```

Now we need to install the Grub2 bootloader to the MBR . . .

NOTE: it is IMPORTANT that you do not enter the partition number here.

Only enter the letter of the partition. Here we are using the first hard disk . . . sda.

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

The successful output should report no errors.

Part Two:

Continue using the same live disk session for the following.

It is now necessary to chroot into your Ubuntu installation in order to run update-grub.

Run each of these commands one by one; again, replacing sda6 with the partition number of your Ubuntu installation . . .

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /

sudo chroot /

sudo update-grub
```

The output should list each of your operating systems or at least your ubuntu installation.

Reboot, and remember to remove your usb device or live cd before logging back in.

If windows is not listed, you can run sudo update-grub again from Ubuntu after you reboot.

Comment: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245 -Part One. Part Two: from personal experience