# Windows 8.1 erased after updating to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-8

So I updated Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 from live USB. I formatted Ubuntu and installed new version. But my Windows 8.1 is gone now, Gparted does not show any Windows partitions..

I am very positive that I've done 'Install Ubuntu alongside Windows'.

Is it possible that this happened, or I for some reason accidentally pressed format Windows and install Ubuntu (very very unlikely)?

Comment: Try with my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482111/i-triple-booted-windows-8-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-pear-os-8-but-then-i-ran-into/482122#482122)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature not a bug.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192

Ubuntu developers do not consider descriptions that are not totally clear to be a bug and software was designed to erase drive, so it is not really a bug. JUst that description of process is not clear that, that is what will happen.

Best to try testdisk and see if it can find old NTFS partition. You may be able to recover some data with it. But anything actually overwritten is gone. Testdisk is in the repository you you can download it into the live installer.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

If testdisk does not show files, then you can try photorec, but it is a long slow process and you need another large drive to copy data to.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Some suggest this for NTFS, but it is not free:

http://www.getdata.com/

Caution: getdataback is not the same and is a scam.

Comment: I didn't have important data per se, I just need my working Win 8.1 with all applications, etc. You say it's 'feature not a bug'. But it never said that it is going to delete Windows 8.1 so it's very confusing. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a single disk, you should check the partition's size on the disk to see if it take up the whole drive.  If so, then you have definitely formatted over your Windows partition.  In that case, you should follow the solution for this question found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu).  If not, perhaps you simply deleted the partition.  Or maybe, although unlikely, Gparted isn't seeing it.  Run `fdisk -l` from a terminal just to be sure.

Also, while a long shot, it doesn't hurt to check out [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) either.